# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unrecognized database version: ' Firebase crash on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app keeps crashing on physical device, but it works on simulator. and I can't find any information on that bug. I am using firebase. My app has been working fine for a while and this randomly occurs.

2016-08-08 14:50:14.081 gameofchats[1626:570752] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unrecognized database version: '
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182462db0 0x181ac7f80 0x182462cf8 0x1001b1bc8 0x1001b1ab0 0x1001c2a84 0x100ed5a7c 0x100ed5a3c 0x100ee2554 0x100ed972c 0x100ee466c 0x100ee4364 0x1820c5470 0x1820c5020)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem but mine is happening when saving the username to the database, I'll tell you if I find anything

Comment: I pod installed, cmd+shift+K, and restarted the app and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced more or less the same issue.

I remove the app from my device and let xCode install a fresh copy of it and that solved the issue.

My guess is that somehow the local Firebase cache must have been corrupted and each time Firebase's sdk tried to access it the app crashs.